# How can I use a source in google code with my project?

Tags: android, android-widget, google-code

Currently I am working on a android project and I found very useful source in Google code. But there is no .jar Library but only .apk file.

So can someone please tell me how to use the resources in Google code more efficiently?

[This](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/) is the project i am referring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That project is already an android library.
Check this [closed issue](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/issues/detail?id=8&can=1).

Answer (score 2):

is it on the source page for that project? http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/source/checkout